# How to read the KEY values from JSONObject in angular response from SprinBoot ResponseEntity

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, angular-httpclient

In my Spring Boot backend i created a JSON Object from a HashMap

```
HashMap<String, ClassData> val = obj.unZipIt(file.getOriginalFilename());
        Gson Jobj = new Gson();
        System.out.println(Jobj.toJson(val));
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(Jobj.toJson(val));
```

In my Angular Frontend i take the JSON Object response

```
 obj= {};

.subscribe(event => {
        if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
          this.progress.percentage = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total);
        } else if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
          console.log(event.body);
          this.obj['Classes'] = Object.values(event.body);
          console.log(this.obj['Classes']);
          document.getElementById("demo-content").style.display = "none";
        }
      }, (err) => {
        (err.error instanceof Error)
          let message = (`Code ${err.status}, Error was: ${err.error.errorMessage}`);
          alert(message)
      }
    );
```

when i print my `event.body` it gives the JSON Response

> {"FileProcessor":{"filepath":"C:\tmp\untitled\src\FileProcessor.java","conceptList":[]},"subClass":{"filepath":"C:\tmp\untitled\src\subClass.java","conceptList":[{"parentClassName":"Main","parentPath":"C:\tmp\untitled\src\Main.java","conceptName":"Inheritence","lineNo":1}]},"ProjectProcessor":{"filepath":"C:\tmp\untitled\src\ProjectProcessor.java","conceptList":[]},"Main":{"filepath":"C:\tmp\untitled\src\Main.java","conceptList":[]},"ProjectReader":{"filepath":"C:\tmp\untitled\src\ProjectReader.java","conceptList":[]}}

when i tries to take the key Values out `this.obj['Classes'] = Object.values(event.body);`
 it gives array which is separated from single character

[image]

is there a way to get the KEY values From the JSON object

Comment: Return a ResponseEntity<Map<<String, ClassData>>: spring will serialize the map to JSON for you, and set the proper content type. You're currently returning text/plain, not application/json. Also, use binding in your frontent, instead of doing DOM manipulations.

Comment: Hi @JBNizet after returning `<Map<<String, ClassData>>` im getting a error like this `ERROR 13112 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine             : [THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-1] Exception processing template "upload": Error resolving template [upload], template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers`

Comment: You need to annotate the method with `@ResponseBody`, or the whole controller with `@RestController`

Comment: @JBNizet Hi i just changed the value to JASON Parse from frontend and it works